# code indentation in Doxygen using Xml comment

Tags: c#, xml, doxygen, indentation

I am trying to look for a way to indent example code in Doxygen but could not find anything about C# and Xml comments. 
Since every attempt is a little long on setting it up and all and I have not found any proper documentation on that issue, I though of asking here.

The idea is to create indentation for C# xml comment. So far I have:

```
    /// <code>public void Method()<br>
    /// {<br>
    /// <blockquote>float x = 10, y = 10 , z = 0;<br>
    /// Vector3 vector = new Vector3 (x, y, z);<br>
    /// if(something)<br>
    /// <blockquote>Other Code</blockquote></br></blockquote>
    /// }</code>
```

But it draws a blue line on the left side:

[image]

Does anyone have a simple and good looking way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
/// \code
/// public void Method()
/// {
///     float x = 10, y = 10 , z = 0;
///     Vector3 vector = new Vector3 (x, y, z);
///     if(something)
///         Other Code
/// }
/// \endcode
```

Much easier to read the source comments too :)

Comment: It actually does work!! Thanks. I tried it with <code><\code> but that was laying it all on one line.